# Renaming Field in QuickSight Dataset generated from S3 CSV files is Persistent after CSV update?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have some CSV files in S3. I connected those CSV files in QuickSight. I added those CSV files through Athena into QuickSight as Dataset. Those CSV files in S3 bucket will be updated frequently everyday. Now, I renamed some Field names of that Dataset into QuickSight (Which are Column Names of CSV).

My question is, if I rename some Fields in QuickSight of the DataSet, whether those Fields will be reverted back to their original names, when the source CSV files will be updated into S3 as they are connected through Athena?

Comment: how is this table in created in Athena ? via crawler or manual DDL?

Comment: @Prabhakar Reddy: Created initially by Crawler and then some issues were there, so created manually later on